# opencv-python termux

Tags: python

### Este error ocurre al intentar instalar opencv-python en termux , tengo el cmake actualizado y me ha funcionado con otras librerías , no soy experto en el tema por eso pudo ayuda , el log está más q claro para qué un experto vea y sepa q es lo q pasa , si alguien me pudiera ayudar sería genial

```
~/EagleEye $ pip install opencv-contrib-python    Collecting opencv-contrib-python                    Using cached opencv-contrib-python-4.5.5.64.tar.gz (150.4 MB)                                       Installing build dependencies ... error           error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.                            │ exit code: 1                                    ╰─> [347 lines of output]                             Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment          Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment           Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment      Collecting setuptools                               Using cached setuptools-61.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)                                          Collecting wheel                                    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)                                            Collecting scikit-build                             Using cached scikit_build-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)                                     Collecting cmake                                    Using cached cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz (31 kB)          Installing build dependencies: started            Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started                                                        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'                                    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started                                                        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'                                  Collecting pip                                      Using cached pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)                                                 Collecting numpy==1.21.2                            Using cached numpy-1.21.2-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl                                           Collecting packaging                                Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)                                              Collecting distro                                   Using cached distro-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)                                                Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2                 Using cached pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)                                             Building wheels for collected packages: cmake                                                         Building wheel for cmake (pyproject.toml): started                                                  Building wheel for cmake (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                 × Building wheel for cmake (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.                               │ exit code: 1                                    ╰─> [303 lines of output]                             Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.                                       CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.                                    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                         See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".                                        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.                                       -- The C compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1                                                    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info                  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done                                                             -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc - skipped                   -- Detecting C compile features                   -- Detecting C compile features - done            -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1                                                  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info                -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done                                                           -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - skipped                -- Detecting CXX compile features                 -- Detecting CXX compile features - done                                                            -- Configuring done                               -- Generating done
            -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_cmake_test_compile/build                                          -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1                                                  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info                -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - skipped                -- Detecting CXX compile features                 -- Detecting CXX compile features - done                                                            -- ***************************************************                                              -- Build CMake from source: ON                    -- ***************************************************                                              -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download                                                           -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download - URL: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.22.3/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz
            -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download - CMakeProject_SOURCE_DIR: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/CMake-src                          -- Looking for __GLIBC__                          -- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found              -- Looking for __GLIBC_MINOR__                    -- Looking for __GLIBC_MINOR__ - not found                                                          -- SuperBuild -   CMakeProject-build              -- SuperBuild -   CMakeProject-build - CMakeProject_BINARY_DIR: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build                                -- SuperBuild -   CMakePythonDistributions                                                          -- Configuring done                               -- Generating done                                CMake Warning:                                      Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:                                                                                              PYTHON_EXECUTABLE                                 PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR                                PYTHON_LIBRARY                                    PYTHON_VERSION_STRING                             SKBUILD                                                                                                                                           -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build                            [  3%] Creating directories for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                         [  6%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                                        -- Downloading...                                    dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz'                                       timeout='none'                                    inactivity timeout='none'                      -- Using src='https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.22.3/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz'                                                         -- [download 100% complete]                       -- [download 0% complete]                         -- [download 1% complete]                         -- [download 2% complete]                         -- [download 3% complete]                         -- [download 4% complete]                         -- [download 5% complete]                         -- [download 6% complete]                         -- [download 7% complete]                         -- [download 8% complete]                         -- [download 9% complete]                         -- [download 10% complete]                        -- [download 11% complete]                        -- [download 12% complete]                        -- [download 13% complete]                        -- [download 14% complete]                        -- [download 15% complete]                        -- [download 16% complete]                        -- [download 17% complete]                        -- [download 18% complete]                        -- [download 19% complete]                        -- [download 20% complete]                        -- [download 21% complete]                        -- [download 22% complete]                        -- [download 23% complete]                        -- [download 24% complete]                        -- [download 25% complete]                        -- [download 26% complete]                        -- [download 27% complete]                        -- [download 28% complete]                        -- [download 29% complete]                        -- [download 30% complete]                        -- [download 31% complete]                        -- [download 32% complete]                        -- [download 33% complete]                        -- [download 34% complete]                        -- [download 35% complete]                        -- [download 36% complete]                        -- [download 37% complete]                        -- [download 38% complete]                        -- [download 39% complete]                        -- [download 40% complete]                        -- [download 41% complete]                        -- [download 42% complete]                        -- [download 43% complete]                        -- [download 44% complete]                        -- [download 45% complete]                        -- [download 46% complete]                        -- [download 47% complete]                        -- [download 48% complete]                        -- [download 49% complete]                        -- [download 50% complete]                        -- [download 51% complete]                        -- [download 52% complete]                        -- [download 53% complete]                        -- [download 54% complete]                        -- [download 55% complete]                        -- [download 56% complete]                        -- [download 57% complete]                        -- [download 58% complete]                        -- [download 59% complete]                        -- [download 60% complete]                        -- [download 61% complete]                        -- [download 62% complete]                        -- [download 63% complete]                        -- [download 64% complete]                        -- [download 66% complete]
            -- [download 67% complete]                        -- [download 68% complete]                        -- [download 69% complete]                        -- [download 70% complete]                        -- [download 71% complete]                        -- [download 72% complete]                        -- [download 73% complete]                        -- [download 74% complete]                        -- [download 75% complete]                        -- [download 76% complete]                        -- [download 77% complete]                        -- [download 78% complete]                        -- [download 79% complete]                        -- [download 80% complete]                        -- [download 81% complete]                        -- [download 82% complete]                        -- [download 83% complete]                        -- [download 84% complete]                        -- [download 85% complete]                        -- [download 86% complete]
            -- [download 87% complete]                        -- [download 88% complete]                        -- [download 89% complete]                        -- [download 90% complete]                        -- [download 91% complete]                        -- [download 92% complete]                        -- [download 93% complete]                        -- [download 94% complete]                        -- [download 95% complete]                        -- [download 96% complete]                        -- [download 97% complete]                        -- [download 98% complete]                        -- [download 99% complete]                        -- [download 100% complete]                       -- verifying file...                                     file='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz'                               -- Downloading... done                            -- extracting...                                       src='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/cmake-3.22.3.tar.gz'                                       dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/CMake-src'                                  -- extracting... [tar xfz]                        -- extracting... [analysis]                       -- extracting... [rename]                         -- extracting... [clean up]                       -- extracting... done                             [  9%] No update step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                               [ 12%] No patch step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                                [ 15%] No configure step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                            [ 18%] No build step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                                [ 21%] No install step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                              [ 24%] Completed 'CMakeProject-src-download'                                                        [ 24%] Built target CMakeProject-src-download                                                       [ 27%] Creating directories for 'LibUV'                                                             [ 30%] No download step for 'LibUV'               [ 33%] No update step for 'LibUV'                 [ 36%] No patch step for 'LibUV'                  [ 39%] No configure step for 'LibUV'              [ 42%] No build step for 'LibUV'                  [ 45%] No install step for 'LibUV'                [ 48%] Completed 'LibUV'                          [ 48%] Built target LibUV                         [ 51%] Creating directories for 'CMakeProject-build'                                                [ 54%] No download step for 'CMakeProject-build'                                                    [ 57%] No update step for 'CMakeProject-build'                                                      [ 60%] No patch step for 'CMakeProject-build'                                                       [ 63%] Performing configure step for 'CMakeProject-build'                                           loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/initial-cache.txt                    loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build-prefix/tmp/CMakeProject-build-cache-Release.cmake                   -- The C compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1                                                    -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 13.0.1                                                  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info                  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed                                                           -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc                             -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc - broken                    CMake Error at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):                                          The C compiler                                                                                        "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc"                                                                                                            is not able to compile a simple test program.                                                                                                         It fails with the following output: 
                Change Dir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp                                                                                                                  Run Build Command(s):/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_8c3ec/fast && make[3]: Entering directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                                     /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/build                                     make[4]: Entering directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                              Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o                                       /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc   -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -D_POSIX_SOURCE=1 -D_SVID_SOURCE=1 -D_BSD_SOURCE=1  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c                       Linking C executable cmTC_8c3ec                   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/link.txt --verbose=1                                         /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -D_POSIX_SOURCE=1 -D_SVID_SOURCE=1 -D_BSD_SOURCE=1  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -lstdc++ -lgcc -lrt  CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_8c3ec                                       ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc                                                         clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                  make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c3ec.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_8c3ec] Error 1                         make[4]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                               make[3]: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_8c3ec/fast] Error 2                                                make[3]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
            Call Stack (most recent call first):                CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)                                                                                                                          -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                         See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".                                                         See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".                                                          make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CMakeProject-build.dir/build.make:95: CMakeProject-build-prefix/src/CMakeProject-build-stamp/CMakeProject-build-configure] Error 1                                             make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:142: CMakeFiles/CMakeProject-build.dir/all] Error 2              make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2               File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-ujipj2_2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 595, in setup                                                     cmkr.make(make_args, env=env)                   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-ujipj2_2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 609, in make                                                               raise SKBuildError(                                                                                                                               --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                    -- Trying "Ninja" generator                       --------------------------------                  ---------------------------                       ----------------------                            -----------------                                 ------------                                      -------                                           --                                                --                                                -------                                           ------------                                      -----------------                                 ----------------------                            ---------------------------                       --------------------------------                  -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                                                                                  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                    -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator              --------------------------------                  ---------------------------                       ----------------------                            -----------------                                 ------------                                      -------                                           --                                                --                                                -------                                           ------------
            -----------------                                 ----------------------                            ---------------------------                       --------------------------------                  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                      Configuring Project                                 Working directory:                                  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build                                                               Command:                                            cmake /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-install/src/cmake/data -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.4 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-ujipj2_2/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                  An error occurred while building with CMake.                                                          Command:                                            cmake --build . --target install --config Release --                                              Source directory:                                   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42                                                     Working directory:                                  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-525xvjv7/cmake_488440b22f5f469391d40ca3ed6dbf42/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.10/cmake-build                                                             Please see CMake's output for more information.                                                     [end of output]                                                                                 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmake
      Failed to build cmake  
                           
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects                                                   [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1                                    
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Tirar un mensaje de error sin indicar qué código lo genera es un poco... optimista. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Este error suele suceder cuando la plataforma no es compatible con dichas librerías, eso es lo que pasa en caso de termux, las librerías  `opencv` y `numpy` no están pensadas para plataformas como termux haciendo que pip mande un error

Para instalar `opencv` y `numpy` en termux debes usar `apt` o `pkg`, ejecutando estos comandos

```
~$ pkg update
~$ pkg in python-numpy -y
~$ pkg in opencv-python -y
```

para saber la versión de `opencv` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
~$ python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
```

O también lo puedes saber de la siguiente manera que es la tradicional

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.6.0'
>>>
```